# Removing all popover then adding popover, doesn't show

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I only want one popover to be opened at a time. So I remove them all and then add a new one, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).on("click", ".priority", function() {
    $(".popover").remove();
    $(this).popover({ /* [...] */ });
});
```

This doesn't show anything like if it was removed after the creation.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwd5v/)

Comment: I'm doing this because I need to know what is the target of the popover. So, instead to save an array on popover targets, I prefer to store one.

Comment: As I would have answered in your last question, I think you are doing this a little backwards. No need for saving the target or trigger, since you already had it on $(this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method `hide`, eg `popover('hide')` :

```
$(document).on("click", ".priority", function() {
    //this will hide all popovers except the popover associated to the clicked .priorioty
    $(".popover").not(this).popover('hide');
    $(this).popover({ /* [...] */ });
});
```

see documentation http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Here is a little demo showing how I would do it (differs from yours, btw also the last (deleted) question regarding "pointed"). Cannot quite understand what you are trying to achieve (thinking about the last question especially) - why do you instantiate the popovers on click, so the user has to click twice? Btw, your fiddle never shows a popover!

```
$('.priority').each(function() {
    $(this).popover({
        title: "Priority value",
        content: '<input id="priorityBox" type="range" min="0" max="100" />',
        container: "#matchRuleForm",
        html: true
    }).on('show.bs.popover', function() {
       $('.priority').not(this).popover('hide');
    });  
})
```

A popover is attached to an element, like `.priority` - so you should target those elements. `.popover` is just injected into the DOM temporarily, and cannot be manipulated by the popover methods, like `.('show')` and `.('hide')`.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4mWE9/** (now the correct link)

Comment: "your fiddle never shows a popover" That's why I ask why it's not showing. "why do you instantiate the popovers on click, so the user has to click twice?" You're right, I'm probably implementing it wrong. And I don't know how you found this deleted question. ^^ /!\ : Your jsfiddle is wrong I think, it's the same as the one I sent, which is a not working case. Did you forget to save ?

Comment: @Elfayer, yes, but why do you instantiate the popover in a click event, then the basic idea with popovers is to automate exactly that behavior? The above is the "bootstrap way" to do it.

Comment: Your implementation doesn't work if the element with `.priority` is created dynamically. Again, your jsfiddle link is the same I posted in my question and doesn't show a solution.

Comment: @Elfayer : Ooops, pasted the wrong jsfiddle, shame on me - it is corrected now! Here -> http://jsfiddle.net/4mWE9/ and in the answer above.

Comment: Ok, nice one. I think you answered the question even if it doesn't completely solve my problem, I'll create a new thread.

Comment: @Elfayer regarding dynamically content, just run a `$('.priority').unbind()` and the above code on the HTML you inject.